# elasticsearch jdbc import data contain json

Tags: mysql, json, elasticsearch

I want to import from mysql to elasticsearch using elasticsearch-jdbc by jprante. The problem is some field in table-x contain json data, but when jdbc exporting to elasticsearch it make it nested properties. I just want it export as is, which is string.

For example

```
table x
id|name       |field_contain_json
pk|varchar(20)|varchar(1000)
```

after export the result is (based on /index/_mapping):

```
{
  "tbl_perseroan": {
    "mappings": {
      "tbl_perseroan": {
        "properties": {
          "field_contain_json": {
            "properties": {
              "sub_field_1": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "sub_field_2": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "sub_field_3": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "sub_field_4": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, I want the result just like this:

```
{
  "tbl_perseroan": {
    "mappings": {
      "tbl_perseroan": {
        "properties": {
          "field_contain_json": {
            "type":"string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you're getting with `detect_json: false`?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with detect_json false. But now the problem is utf encoding longer than max length 32766